# How to use throttle function after value change, after couple of seconds?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i have a throttle function but i think i am using if the wrong way. The function `setGlobalFilter` fires every time the value change. But it has to be after a couple of seconds. So i use the throttle function for it. But the function doesn't fire after a couple of seconds, because the globalFilter stills fire itself every time the values change. What am i doing wrong?

```
  function GlobalFilter({ globalFilter, setGlobalFilter }) {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(globalFilter)
    const onChange = throttle((value) => {
      setGlobalFilter(value || undefined)
    }, 400)
    return (
      <span className={styles.component}>
        <input
          className={styles.input}
          value={value || ''}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setValue(e.target.value)
            onChange(e.target.value)
          }}
          placeholder={`Zoek in deze tabel`}
        />
      </span>
    )
  }
  function fuzzyTextFilterFn(rows, id, filterValue) {
    return matchSorter(rows, filterValue, { keys: [(row) => row.values[id]] })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like with debouncing, you need to memoize the throttled function, otherwise it gets recreated every render. You can do this with `useMemo`:

```
const onChange = useMemo(() => throttle((value) => {
  setGlobalFilter(value || undefined)
}, 400), []);
```

Comment: if i am using this i get `React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead.`

Comment: Based on this: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19240 looks like `useCallback` is only for inline functions. Gotta use `useMemo` instead. Updated my answer

Comment: Also just Google the error message first, that one I linked was the 2nd result. Will likely find an answer to the problem